# ESTA and passport validity period - potential problems?

Tags: usa, passports, esta

I am an EU citizen planning to travel to the USA using the ESTA in March 2015. My passport expires on September 16 2015. According to the website I should have passport valid for 6 months although that is waived for many countries.

If I go the first week of March for a couple of days and come back it won't be a problem will it?

Because if we count from March 11 till September 18 it is exactly 6 months. But I am still concerned. Can anybody inform me please in order to avoid any problems and disallowance.

Comment: Greek nationality

Answer (score 3):

If your planned departure date from the US is March 11, and your passport expires after September 11, then you will satisfy the passport validity requirement. You should have no problem with this aspect of your travel.

Comment: @pnuts: Interesting, I always thought it was a policy of the destination country, rather than a policy of the passport-issuing country.